# Should Consumer process messages, then send messages back to Kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'd like to process data from a Consumer with topic1, then send messages back into Kafka to topic2

`Kafka --> Consumer (processing messages) from topic1, then call a Producer to send processed message to topic2 --> Kafka`

My try:

```
 consumer.on('message', (message) => {
     let processedMsg = processMessage(message);

     payloads = [
        { topic: 'topic2', messages: processedMsg }
     ];

     producer.on('ready', function () {
         producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
             console.log(data);
         });
     });

     producer.on('error', function (err) {})
});
```

But, Producer cannot send processed messages into Kafka. The error what I got

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 ready listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I use node module `Kafka-node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the order of the producer ready listener and the consumer message listener.

Otherwise, you're setting up the ready listener for each and every consumed message

For example

```
 producer.on('ready', function () {
    consumer.on('message', (message) => {
      let processedMsg = processMessage(message);

      payloads = [
       { topic: 'topic2', messages: processedMsg }
      ];

       producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
         console.log(data);
       });
 });
```

I would suggest looking at this library, though, if mostly processing and forwarding to new topics https://github.com/nodefluent/kafka-streams/